Reproducing Greens functions in a paper
In this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.2130), there has been a mention of how to derive the Greens functions (first talked about in Eq(6,7)) from Hamiltonians in Eq(4). There are two constant hamiltonians here: the Resonant model one giving $\mathcal{G}(t)$:
$$H_{RL} = \sum_k k:c^\dagger_k c_k: + V\sum_kc^\dagger_kd + d^\dagger c_k,$$ and the potential scattering model giving $\mathcal{G}^{(n)}(t)$:
$$H_S = \sum_k k:c^\dagger_k c_k: + g \langle S_z(t) \rangle \sum_{kk'} :c^\dagger_kc_{k'}.$$
Here, since the local operators don't evolve in time, for half of the time period, $$\langle S_z(t) \rangle = \langle S_z(n\tau + \tau/2)  \rangle$$ which is constant for the half time period of $\mathcal{G}^{(n)}(\tau/2)$ calculation. Appendix A mentions using equations of motions approach to arrive at the Greens functions matrix elements, which I understand as:
$$i \frac{d}{dt}G_{ll'}(t) = \delta(t) + i\theta(t) \langle \{[H,c_l(t)],c^\dagger_{l'}\} \rangle$$
$$i \frac{d}{dt}G_{ll'}(t) = \delta(t) + i\theta(t) \sum_m G_{lm}(t) \langle \{[H,c_m],c^\dagger_{l'}\} \rangle.$$
Solving for this gets me coupled differential equations which do not really lead me to the correct answer it seems. The equations I get are:
$$\dot{\mathcal{G}}^{(n)}_{ld} = 0,\quad \dot{\mathcal{G}}^{(n)}_{lk} = -k\mathcal{G}^{(n)}_{lk} - g\langle S_z(t) \rangle \sum_m \mathcal{G}^{(n)}_{lm}$$ $$\dot{\mathcal{G}}_{ld} = -V\sum_m \mathcal{G}_{lm}, \quad \dot{\mathcal{G}}_{lk} = -V\mathcal{G}_{ld} - k\mathcal{G}_{lk}.$$
The sum over $m$ is only over $k$, and does not involve the local operator $d$. Can someone please describe where I might be going wrong?
Edit: These are the anti-commutation relations I used to arrive to my result: $$\{c_l,c_{l'}^\dagger\} = \delta_{ll'}, \quad \{d,d^\dagger\} = 1$$$$\{c_l,d^\dagger\} = \{c_l,d\} = 0,\quad \{c_l^\dagger,c_{l'}^\dagger\} = 0$$
